# Finding combinations of two columns in excel, with a condition in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations

I am trying to count the combination of columns A and B, by fixing a value for column B and excluding all the duplicates.

In the exemple bellow, I would like to count all unique combinations of column A & B where B is equal to "green". The result should be 4

```
A     B  
one   green  
one   green  
two   green  
four  pink  
three  green
four  pink  
blue  green  
black white  
black white
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had to do this before, you can accomplish this using an array formula with the frequency function.

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B10="green",MATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10,0)),ROW(A2:A10)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))
```

Note: This formula must be entered using `ctrl+shift+enter`

For a complete explanation of how this works please see this article:

[Count unique text values](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria)

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to have Excel 2016+, with the new `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions, you can use:

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(myRng,INDEX(myRng,0,2)="green")))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice - I didn't know this was available now!